# Property 'setComputed' is optional in type ... but required in type 'EntityExample'

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm trying to write a factory for update of entity, but using afterload is throwing an error:

Entity:

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  OneToMany,
  BaseEntity,
  AfterLoad,
} from "typeorm";
import { OtherEntity } from "./OtherEntity";

// ColumnNumericTransformer
export class ColumnNumericTransformer {
  to(data: number): number {
    return data;
  }
  from(data: string): number {
    return parseFloat(data);
  }
}

@Entity()
export class EntityExample extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column("numeric", {
    precision: 7,
    scale: 2,
    transformer: new ColumnNumericTransformer(),
    default: 0,
  })
  GGR: number;

  @Column("numeric", {
    precision: 7,
    scale: 2,
    transformer: new ColumnNumericTransformer(),
    default: 0,
  })
  bets: number;

  @Column("numeric", {
    precision: 7,
    scale: 2,
    transformer: new ColumnNumericTransformer(),
    default: 0,
  })
  wins: number;

  @Column({ default: 0 })
  fee_percentage: number;

  @Column("numeric", {
    precision: 7,
    scale: 2,
    transformer: new ColumnNumericTransformer(),
    default: 0,
  })
  fee_amount: number;

  @OneToMany((type) => OtherEntity, (some) => some.data)
  relations: OtherEntity[];

  @AfterLoad()
  setComputed() {
    this.GGR = this.bets - this.wins;
    this.fee_amount = this.GGR * (this.fee_percentage/100);
  }
}
```

Factory:

```
update: async(attrs: Partial<EntityExample> = {}) => {
    let entityExample = await getRepository(EntityExample).findOne(attrs.id);
    entityExample = {...entityExample, ...attrs};
    let updated_entity_example;

    try {
        updated_entity_example = await getRepository(EntityExample).save(entityExample);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error("Couln't save Entity Example")
    }
    return updated_entity_example
  }
```

TypeORM error:

```
Property 'setComputed' is optional in type '{ id: string; name: string; GGR: number; bets: number; wins: number; fee_percentage: number; fee_amount: number; setComputed?: () => void; hasId?: () => boolean; save?: (options?: SaveOptions) => Promise<...>; remove?: (options?: RemoveOptions) => Promise<...>; softRemove?: (options?: SaveOptions...' but required in type 'EntityExample'
```

So, the question is how can I solve it? Should I pass setComputed to the factory every time? Or is there a better way? Maybe it worth to use different methods? Which ones are better?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that partial means that properties can be undefined, if you do this {...{ foo: 'bar'}, ...{ foo: undefined}} then you will get { foo: undefined }. Because of this typescript will use the possibly undefined type option. Since the function properties probably aren't going to be passed in on attrs you may be able to omit anything with a function signature and have it work, so something like

```
update: async(attrs: Partial<OmitOnType<EntityExample, (...args: any) => any>> = {}) => {
```

Edit: Typescripts Omit won't take anything that isn't a string number or symbol, to be able to omit types you can use a type map that looks like this

```
 type OmitOnType<T, U> = {
     [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends U ? never : P
};
```

Comment: I have this message when I edit `Type '(...args: any) => any' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.`

Comment: Right the native typescript Omit doesn't take types like this, you can create your own utility type that I have added to the comment that will allow you to do it.

Comment: With this it showing type error: `Types of property 'game_id' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | "game_id"' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: What is the return type of await getRepository(...).findOne();